# How to generate Authorization header (String variable) in API interface with Oauth security scheme object in OpenApi3.0.2 swagger codegen?

Tags: java, oauth, jax-rs, openapi, swagger-codegen

Tools:
Swagger for OpenApi 3.0.2 maven dependency:

```
<groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
<artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0.16</version>
```

language: jaxrs-cxf

Using latest templates fetched from [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen-generators/blob/master/src/main/resources/handlebars/JavaJaxRS/cxf/)

I defined my oauth object in my specs and assigned it to a method:

```
paths:
  /endpoint:
    method:
      operationId: functionName
      security:
        - oauthSample:
          - aScope

components:
  securitySchemes:
    oauthSample:
      type: oauth2
      flows:
        authorizationCode:
          authorizationUrl: {someurl}
          tokenUrl: {someurl}
          refreshUrl: {someurl}
          scopes:
            aScope: a scope
```

I expect, in the generated Java code, to have:

```
functionName(other params of the endpoint function, @HeaderParam("Authorization") String var4, ...)
```

Except there is nothing related to this security object generated.
A workaround could be to also add an Authorization header in the security of the endpoint.
But then defining an oauth security scheme is worthless (in terms of code generated) and confusing (in terms of specs since there will both be an oauth and an Authorization/Basic authentication through the Authorization header scheme).

Am I missing something?

I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/5103), except it's for openapitools rather than swagger v3 (because apparently openapitools is a fork of swagger v2 and the way to move forward). But I'd be happy to have an actual support of security objects whether it be on one or the other :)

Comment: In your spec, `scopes` must be inside `authorizationCode`. Maybe this is why the security code is not generated.

Comment: That was a typo in the post. Rectified. Did you succeed in having a security code generated?

Comment: I didn't actually try, just pointed out a error/typo in the spec. Your current spec looks valid, so it can be a codegen bug. Consider opening an issue in the codegen repository: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues